# python multithreading - one thread working, another waiting

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two python scripts that need to be integrated in one script running on two different threads. I cannot integrate them in the same script since one of the scripts must perform a task every 2 minutes by sending data through MQTT, but the second one should be able to recieve web requests at any time, so I cannot just merge the scripts... can you suggest me a way of running it with multithreading by having one thread that runs once at every two minutes and the second one to run continuously. 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, use the `threading` or `multiprocessing` modules. Seriously though, what have you tried so far?

Comment: if the two processes need to talk to each other, use a Queue.Queue

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained why you can't combine them.  This is the obvious solution (assuming everything in both scripts is thread-safe, which it must be, since you are considering this at all).

```
from threading import Thread

from program_a import do_a
from program_B import do_b

def main():
    a = Thread(target=do_a)
    b = Thread(target=do_b)
    a.start()
    b.start()
    a.join()
    b.join()

main()
```

The use of threads is exactly what will allow program_a to update MQTT every two minutes while program_b continuously services web requests.